# Integrate odds ratio and CI with p-value in Fisher test R

Tags: r

For each row of the matrix, I want to calculate p-value, odds ratio and 95% CI of odds ratio.
I can calculate Fisher p-value as follows:

```
df <- read.table(text="
          h_p    d_p    h_a    d_a
                  bgc1    0         10          1        3
                  bgc2    0          0          5           25
                  ", header=T, row.names=1)
Fisher_output<-data.frame(apply(df, 1, 
      function(x) {
        tbl <- matrix(as.numeric(x[1:4]), ncol=2, byrow=T) # converting each matrix row to contingency tables
        fisher.test(tbl, alternative="two.sided")$p.value
      }))
```

I want my final output in the format:

```
P-value OR  95%_CI
BGC1    xxx yyy zzz1-zzz2
BGC2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the components with `tidy` from `broom`

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
   tbl <- matrix(as.numeric(x[1:4]), ncol=2, byrow=T)
  ft <- fisher.test(tbl, alternative="two.sided")
  tidy(ft) %>% 
     select(estimate, p.value, conf.low, conf.high) }) %>% 
 bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
```